# Sometimes with Feathers?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> When in red, I was very loud.
> In high definition, a treasure.
> You put me in to interfere.
> Rest on me for your leisure.
>
> Put me between the last two letters,
> I am an Asian plant.
> Keep some of me in the water,
> And being unsettled you can't.

**What am I?**
**Please explain each line in your answer.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Surely you must be

> an **oar**.

When in red, I was very loud.

> r**oar**ed

In high definition, a treasure.

> h**oar**d

You put me in to interfere.

> to "put an oar in" is an idiom for interfering in other people's business

Rest on me for your leisure.

> "rest on your oars" is an idiom as well.

Put me between the last two letters,
I am an Asian plant.

> Solved by @[Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv) in the comment section (would never have gotten it myself):
>
>  The last two letters are, in this case, "zed" and "y", giving [zed**oar**y](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/zedoary).

Keep some of me in the water,

> Rowing

And being unsettled you can't.

> If you remain calm and collected, you "keep both oars in the water"

Title: "Sometimes with Feathers?"

> turning an oar in a particular way when rowing is called feathering the oar.

Comment: my guess is the same! but also stuck on the asian plant haha

Comment: Your Asian plant is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curcuma_zedoaria) - rot13(MRQBNEL) :)

Comment: Everything as intended, well done! And apologies about the asian plant, I know that one is a bit obscure (thanks to Stiv for the contribution).